# Jax rs client pool

Tags: client, jax-rs, cxf

I am working on setting up a REST Client using jax-rs 2 client API.
In the api doc it says "Clients are heavy-weight objects that manage the client-side communication infrastructure. Initialization as well as disposal of a Client instance may be a rather expensive operation. It is therefore advised to construct only a small number of Client instances in the application." (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html). As per this statement it sounds like Client is not thread-safe and i should not be using single Client instance for all requests.

I am using CXF implementation, so far i didn't find a way to set up pool for Client objects.

If anyone has any information reg this could you please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, CXF uses a transport based on the in-JDK HttpURLConnection object to perform HTTP requests.

Connection pooling is performed allowing persistent connections to reuse the underlying socket connection for multiple http requests.

Set these system properties to configure the pool(default values)

```
http.keepalive=true
http.maxConnections=5
```

Increment the value of http.maxConnections to set the maximum number of idle connections that will be simultaneously kept alive, per destination. See in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#MiscHTTP) the complete list of properties properties.html

In this post are explained some detail how it works

[Java HttpURLConnection and pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208950/java-httpurlconnection-and-pooling)

Note also that the default JAX-RS client is not thread-safe by default. Check the limitations for proper use [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ThreadSafety)

When you need many requests executed simultaneosly CXF can also use the asynchronous apache HttpAsyncClient. Ser details here

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-client-http-transport.html

Comment: so we just initialize ClientBuilder.newClient() on server start up with http.maxConnections=5 and we will have jax-rs client pool ?

Comment: Yes, it is. The default value of the pool for `http.maxConnections` is 5, so for this case is not needed to configure anything. If you plan to reuse the `Client` check also the the Thread-Safety considerations at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ThreadSafety

Comment: Thanks @pedrofb, I will try this and if it works i will accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @PrasadA, Do you checked the solution?